# Missing Javadoc style comments in generated Doxygen documentation

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I'm struggling to get my code comments to appear in Doxygen's generated documentation. I've been using the Doxygen wizard and the C language. Here's an example comment:

```
/**
 * Takes string formatted plugin information and processes it.
 * @param id_orig a constant
 * @param group_orig a constant
 * @see get_or_add_info(...)
 * @return SUCCESS and FAILURE macros. 
 */
static RETCODE import_process_element(...) { ...}
```

The opening comments show up as expected. Here's the header comment at the beginning of the file:

```
/**
 * @file
 * @brief A super great file.
 * @author Tinus Lorvolds
 */
```

`JAVA_AUTOBRIEF` is on. Doxyfile version 1.8.14 on Windows 7 with C source files. I'm sure this is something simple, but I've been stuck on it for quite awhile. Thank you for your help and patience.

Here's the relevant diff between my configuration and the standard one:

```
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
```

**Solution below.**

Comment: Don't place a file on pastebin or similar, just indicate (in the question) the differences between your doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) and the standard doxygen configuration file. Maybe have a look at the setting `EXTRACT_STATIC`.

Comment: Edited for the diff. I have `EXTRACT_STATIC` set to true, but I've also generated a fresh copy with the setting off -- no change.

Comment: I have no problems. I pasted the 2 code snippets in aa.c (inserting int arguments on the ... and added return1; as body), created default Doxyfile (doxygen -g) and made the modifications as indicated.

Comment: I've just found the issue -- It's not with Doxygen or it's configs. The source I'm working with has a ton of macros and preprocessor guards. One of those directives is hiding the source from Doxygen. By disabling preprocessing I was able to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the source itself. A preprocessor directive was hiding the source from Doxygen. If the settings listed above are all set correctly, try disabling this feature:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = NO
```